# Android ViewPager display issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

[image]

There's a space in top of my PageTabStrip

Here's the code i my activity :

```
mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this , wpPostGroupsArray, mLastLocation);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentItemSelected = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

It seems correct to me. Where could that come from ?

Here's the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/action_bar"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: post the xml code here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line was the problem :

actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);